# current month record should be display from table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

please assist me to correct it.i want to show current month data i tried this but its showing error the literal is too long :

```
number  date
10      20-Jan-2018
20      30-Oct-2018
30      24-Sep-2018
24      01-Oct-2018

select number
from table
where date <= to_char(sysdate,'mm');
```

Comment: What type is your `date` column?  Is it text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `date` column contains text.  You should ideally always store date information in proper date columns.  As a workaround, we can go in the other direction and use `TO_DATE` on your date column, to compare it to the first of the current month:

```
SELECT number
FROM yourTable
WHERE TO_DATE(date, 'dd-mon-yyyy') < TRUNC(sysdate, 'mm');
```